# Horizontal alignment problem with multicols and gather

Tags: equations, amsmath, multicol

So this is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Random text
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \noindent\begin{gather}
        T_{1}=0.005 sec\notag\\
        A_{1}=35.35rpm\notag
    \end{gather}\break
    \begin{gather}
        T_{2}=0.025 sec\notag\\
        A_{2}=11.5rpm\notag
    \end{gather}
\end{multicols} 
\end{document}
```

As you can see, T_{1} and T_{2} are not horizontally aligned and the same for A_{1} and A_{2}, how can i solve?

Here is the problem:
[image]

Comment: Use `\columnbreak` , not `\break`. The latter breaks the line (which is the extra space you see above T2)

Comment: Solved. If you want make it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`multicol` package documentation](http://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf) lists the command for manual breaking across columns with `\columnbreak`, not `\break` (which is what I assume you want to do).

The latter 'breaks' the line, which is the extra space you see above T2.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Random text
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \noindent\begin{gather}
        T_{1}=0.005 sec\notag\\
        A_{1}=35.35rpm\notag
    \end{gather}\columnbreak % <------------
    \begin{gather}
        T_{2}=0.025 sec\notag\\
        A_{2}=11.5rpm\notag
    \end{gather}%
\end{multicols} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you really want `multicols`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for text

\DeclareSIUnit{\rpm}{rpm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align*}
T_{1} &= \SI{0.005}{\second} & T_{2} &= \SI{0.025}{\second} \\
A_{1} &= \SI{35.35}{\rpm}    & A_{2} &= \SI{11.5}{\rpm}
\end{align*}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Note that the official symbol for the second is “s”. You can change it for `siunitx`, if you really need to.

[image]