# Alignment problem when using gather with multicol

Tags: multicol, gather

I have an alignment problem similar to that which is found in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388950/horizontal-alignment-problem-with-multicols-and-gather). But using column break did not solve my problem as it did in this question.

I guess I could try align, but it would be annoying to rewrite everything in this new format. Is there a way to adapt this code to ensure the alignment is acceptable?

Here is some example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\subsubsection*{Omaha}
\begin{gather*}
F = FB \neq \textbf{MB = MBS} \\
M = \textbf{MZ = MBD }\neq FZ \\
B = MZS = FBS \neq FZS \\
Z = MZD = FBD \neq FZD 
\end{gather*}
\columnbreak
\subsubsection*{Crow}
\begin{gather*}
F = \textbf{FB = FZS} \neq MB \\
M = MZ \neq \textbf{FZ = FZD} \\
B = FBS = MZS \neq MBS \\
Z = FBD = MZD \neq MBD 
\end{gather*}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `gather` will always center each line separately.  Use `align*` instead, placing the `&` at the beginning of the line so that every line is aligned at the left.

Answer (score 1):

With use of the `tabularx` table instead of the `multicol` environment:

[image]

(red lines show text borders)

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} X @{} X @{}}
\subsubsection*{Omaha}
\begin{gather*}
F = FB \neq \mathbf{MB = MBS} \\
M = \mathbf{MZ = MBD }\neq FZ \\
B = MZS = FBS \neq FZS \\
Z = MZD = FBD \neq FZD
\end{gather*}
    &
\subsubsection*{Crow}
\begin{gather*}
F = \mathbf{FB = FZS} \neq MB \\
M = MZ \neq \mathbf{FZ = FZD} \\
B = FBS = MZS \neq MBS \\
Z = FBD = MZD \neq MBD
\end{gather*}
\end{tabularx}
or

\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} X @{} X @{}}
\subsubsection*{Omaha}
\[\begin{aligned}
F & = FB \neq \mathbf{MB = MBS} \\
M & = \mathbf{MZ = MBD }\neq FZ \\
B & = MZS = FBS \neq FZS \\
Z & = MZD = FBD \neq FZD
\end{aligned}\]
    &
\subsubsection*{Crow}
\[\begin{aligned}
F & = \mathbf{FB = FZS} \neq MB \\
M & = MZ \neq \mathbf{FZ = FZD} \\
B & = FBS = MZS \neq MBS \\
Z & = FBD = MZD \neq MBD
\end{aligned}\]
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use instead a tabular environnement with some minipages such like this :

```
\begin{tabular}{p{.5\textwidth}p{.5\textwidth}}
    \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
        \subsubsection*{Omaha}
        $
        F = FB \neq \textbf{MB = MBS} \\
        M = \textbf{MZ = MBD }\neq FZ \\
        B = MZS = FBS \neq FZS \\
        Z = MZD = FBD \neq FZD 
        $
    \end{minipage}
    &
    \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
        \subsubsection*{Crow}
        $
        F = \textbf{FB = FZS} \neq MB \\
        M = MZ \neq \textbf{FZ = FZD} \\
        B = FBS = MZS \neq MBS \\
        Z = FBD = MZD \neq MBD 
        $
    \end{minipage}  
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: this is definitely an improvement - but it removes the centering of the equations for me. How might I maintain the formatting of the equations in the example? (i.e. off set the heading with centereed equations?)